# No sound with particular video (WMV) file(s)

Tags: audio, video, windows-media-player, wmv, wma

I've encountered an issue and can't seem to find a solution. I get no sound when I play a video, I've tried a lot of stuff, nothing yields a working file.

1. Codec packs, KLite Mega, CCCP
2. Tried players, GOM, VLC, WMP 10, 11, WMP classic
3. Tried converters, MMConvert, Mediacoder

Other videos are fine, and I've tried it on multiple computers, so it's definitely the file. I have many files like this and all were collected the same, suggesting an encoding issue/quirk. The kicker is, I had it working at some point in VLC, then the other day it up and stopped working. I don't know what changed, nor how to get it working again. I'd like to get to the bottom of it with some help from the helpful people here, to improve my understanding of such issues.

It says WMA v2 codec, which is common I would imagine. My only guess is that something happened during the encoding process that led to this issue, but knowing that I had it working, I'd like to determine how. Is there anything strange about the info below?

Here is the information from mediacoder.

```
General
Complete name : C:\Users\task.wmv
Format : Windows Media
File size : 196 MiB
Duration : 24mn 51s
Overall bit rate mode : Variable
Overall bit rate : 1 102 Kbps
Maximum Overall bit rate : 2 614 Kbps
Encoded date : UTC 2012-05-01 16:06:43.187 

Video
ID : 2
Format : WMV2
Codec ID : WMV2
Codec ID/Info : Windows Media Video 8
Description of the codec : Windows Media Video V8
Duration : 24mn 51s
Bit rate mode : Variable
Bit rate : 536 Kbps
Width : 640 pixels
Height : 360 pixels
Display aspect ratio : 16:9
Frame rate : 15.000 fps
Bit depth : 8 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.155
Stream size : 95.3 MiB (49%)

Language : English (US)

Audio
ID : 1
Format : WMA
Format version : Version 2
Codec ID : 161
Codec ID/Info : Windows Media Audio
Description of the codec : Windows Media Audio 9.2 - 20 kbps, 32 kHz, mono (A/V) 1-pass CBR
Duration : 24mn 51s
Bit rate mode : Constant
Bit rate : 1 411 Kbps
Channel(s) : 1 channel
Sampling rate : 32.0 KHz
Bit depth : 16 bits
Stream size : 251 MiB
Language : English (US)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the file through [AsfBin](http://www.radioactivepages.com/asfbin.aspx) might help. Add the file to the list of input files, make sure that a valid destination is set, and click the `Cut/Copy/Join` button.

If that doesn't help then I suggest that you extract the individual audio and video stream from the file ('demux') and that you check if the audio stream isn't just all silence.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the response.  I tried what you said but still no audio.  I cut/copy/joined with just audio checked and got an asf file, and it is all silence in Audacity.  I remembered that to fix the issue previously I replaced the video card (strange, I know), it was not VLC.  I need to go back to my initial assumptions and determine which file specifically was working.  I'll follow up in a few days.

Comment: I don't think the files have audio, if I determine them to have audio but can't get it to play, I may follow up.  Thanks for the help.